# RequireJs r.js load !tpl files error

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, r.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm using requireJs with uderscore and tpl , I've changed the default file ending from .html to .tpl .
Now if I try to optimize my app i got the following error

```
Tracing dependencies for: app
Error: Error: Loader plugin did not call the load callback in the build:
tpl:
  tpl!module/home/template/home_unnormalized2
  tpl!module/home/template/home
 /*
    more templates
 */
Module loading did not complete for: app, /* failed for all modules */
    at Function.build.checkForErrors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28424:19)
```

it seems like that r.js can't handle the .tpl or !tpl ending/beginning.

my build js

```
({
    baseUrl: "js/lib",
    appDir: "..",
    dir: "dist",

    tpl: {
        extension: '.tpl' // default = '.html'
    },

    modules: [
        { name: "app" }
    ],

    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        underscore: 'underscore',
        text: 'text',
        tpl: 'tpl',

        //Module
        home : '../module/home/home',
    },

    shim : {

    }
})
```